# how to delete a specific row from a table sqlalchemy with flask?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

i want to delete specific row in a db.table
i have these code

```
num_rows_deleted=db.session.query(Orders).filter(Orders.c.id==id).first()
db.session.delete(num_rows_deleted)
db.session.commit()

Orders = db.Table('orders', db.Model.metadata,
            db.Column('id', db.Integer,primary_key=True),
              db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
              db.Column('book_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('books.id')),
              db.Column('quantity', db.Integer,default=1, nullable=False),
              db.Column('created_at',db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now),
            db.Column('updated_at',db.DateTime, onupdate=datetime.datetime.now))
```

these is the table

but i get these error and i dont know how to fix it
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'sqlalchemy.util._collections.result' is not mapped

Comment: Hi Wael, please show us the output as you get it in your python terminal, this will help people identify the issue. Also writing a toy problem that's shows your issue can help in resolving the issue faster.

Comment: hi, these is the error that i get sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'sqlalchemy.util._collections.result' is not mapped

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete a record by id in Flask-SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27158573/how-to-delete-a-record-by-id-in-flask-sqlalchemy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you all - i used Deleting Rows from the Many to Many Table¶
from these site https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html

my table is a seconday table and it is connected to two tables , so i used remove to delete , and append to add .

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead, not fetching the value, but deleting it immediately, using [`Query.delete`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html?highlight=query%20delete#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.delete):

```
db.session.query(Orders).filter(Orders.c.id==id).delete()
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: thank you for ur answer , i get the same problem
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'class_'

Comment: What is the value of `id`? Is it a number or something else?

Comment: yes its a number - and itis the primary key of the order table. these the whole function from the views.py                      @app.route('/delete_order/<int:id>',methods=["GET", "POST"])
@flask_login.login_required
def delete_order(id):                                                                                
 row_to_delete = db.session.query(Orders).filter(Orders.c.id == id).delete()
    db.session.delete(row_to_delete)
    db.session.commit()

Comment: Remove the `db.session.delete(row_to_delete)` part, just leave exactly what I wrote

Comment: still the same thing AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'class_'

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
row_to_delete = db.session.query(Orders).filter(Orders.id==id).one()
db.session.delete(row_to_delete)
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: i try to use these code but i get AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'id'